# Can't get UV mapping on "back side" of plane mesh

Tags: mesh

I've created an object originally from a plane. I ended up solidifying it so it has two sides. I have an issue however when I UV unwrap it, only one side is represented. So in unreal engine 4, one side is lit, the other is just black though.

How do I unwrap it so it shows the front side, and the backside?

Thanks.

Comment: Possibly you simply need to Apply your solidify modifier. You should then be able to unwrap app faced of the mesh.

Comment: Wow, awesome. That was it lol, thank you. I'm not totally clear when it's necessary to apply the modifier, and when not to. Clearly, I should have tried that. Thank you.

Comment: @RichSedman if you want to add in your answer I'll upvote that.

Comment: Glad to help - I’ve added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ‘unwrap’ operation works on the base mesh. If you have any modifiers (such as Solidify) these need to be ‘Applied’ before you unwrap your mesh - otherwise the geometry generated by those modifiers won’t be included. By applying the modifier the base mesh will be updated to include the new geometry and the ‘unwrap’ will include the additional faces.